# PowerShell New-item - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a tool in powershell which includes a function to create a folder structure based on user input. Below is the relevant code:

```
function set-drvsource{
    Write-Host "INFO: Querying Driver Source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    try{
        Write-Host "INFO: Creating standard folder structure" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath" | Out-Null
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath\Source" | Out-Null
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath\Package" | Out-Null
    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "ERROR: Could not create folder structure" -ForegroundColor Red
        Exit
    }
    Write-Host "INFO: Moving local source to new source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Copy-Item $src "$drvpath\Source" -Recurse
}
function main{
    set-drvsource
}
$drvroot = "\\server\share\tmp"
$src = Read-Host "Please provide local driver source path"
$vendor = Read-Host "Device Vendor eg. DELL, HP, Microsoft"
$dmd = Read-Host "Device Model eg. HP Elitebook 840 G3"
$dos = Read-Host "Operating System eg. W7 or W10"
$dac = Read-Host "x64 or x86"
$drvpath = "$drvroot\$vendor\$dmd $dos $dac"
```

If I run this, it triggers the catch statement and throws the following error:

```
$Error[0]
New-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:9 char:1
+ New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath" | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewI 
   temCommand
```

The interesting thing is, if I run the following in a new PowerShell session, it works as expected:

```
$drvroot = "\\server\share\tmp"
$vendor = Read-Host "Vendor"
$dmd = Read-Host "Device Model eg. HP Elitebook 840 G3"
$dos = Read-Host "Operating System eg. W7 or W10"
$dac = Read-Host "x64 or x86"
$drvpath = "$drvroot\$vendor\$dmd $dos $dac"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath" | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath\Source" | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$drvpath\Package" | Out-Null
```

I've doubled checked and $drvpath does survive through to the function, so its not a scope issue?
Any help would be much appreciated! :'(

EDIT: Output of $ERROR[0] | fl -force

```
Exception             : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not 
                        set to an instance of an object.
                           at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.PowerShell.Prov
                        ider.CMDriveProvider.NewItem(String path, String 
                        itemTypeName, Object newItemValue)
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal
                        .NewItemPrivate(CmdletProvider providerInstance, 
                        String path, String type, Object content, 
                        CmdletProviderContext context)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NullReferenceException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
                        ands.NewItemCommand
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at set-drvsource, C:\temp\quick
                        import_cli-1.1\quickimport_cli-1.1\Invoke-QuickImport.p
                        s1: line 51
                        at main, C:\temp\quickimport_cl
                        i-1.1\quickimport_cli-1.1\Invoke-QuickImport.ps1: line 
                        101
                        at <ScriptBlock>, C:\temp\quick
                        import_cli-1.1\quickimport_cli-1.1\Invoke-QuickImport.p
                        s1: line 165
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

Comment: Show output from `$Error[0] | fl -Force`.

Comment: Added @PetSerAl

Comment: `\\server\share\tmp` -> `filesystem::\\server\share\tmp`

Comment: When I try that it throws - The module 
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core' could not be loaded :/ @PetSerAl

Comment: I think there was something wrong with my ISE session, that filesystem:: trick worked :D thanks @PetSerAl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the $drvroot variable with the FileSystem provider, as PetSerAl suggested, resolved the problem.